# MS Access/SQL - Join two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables tbl_sbc and tbl_jdf both tables have the Users and Access fields.
I want to create a new table based on the equality of the users from tbl_sbc and tbl_jdf and sum up the access.

Example

**tbl_sbc**

```
User Access
Foo  20
Bar  5
```

**tbl_jdf**

```
User Access
Foo 35
Beef 50
```

**Output**

```
User Access
Foo  55
Bar  5
Beef 50
```

How would I go about doing so? I can't seem to sum up the values

Comment: Kindly click on the check mark next to answer to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
Select User, Sum(Access) As Total from
(Select User , Access from tbl_sbc
Union All
Select User , Access from tbl_jdf)
Group by User
order by user desc
```